# Parallax mapping glitch in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

[image]
[image]

And this is result when I invert the tangent vector right after transferring it to vertex shader:

[image]
[image]

**The "shadow" is in the wrong place.**

(And it works only when I rotate it through Y axis so the last image seem to present a good parallax mapped cube)

**IM SURE IT IS NOT A TANGENT VECTOR OR TEXTURE COORDINATES PROBLEM**

Because

I used **exactly the same tangent calculation functions** and **exactly the same cube position, normal and texture coordinate data** as in working demo.
After all, I exported arrays with position/texcoord/normal/tangent data into a .txt file and I saw what I exactly expected (and what I expected is the same pos/tex/norm data as in working demo, including calculated tangents which I managed to export from working demo).

The next argument is, I copied my shader code to a working demo and **it still works**.
Other one is, I tried multiple ways to render this cube.
I tried VBO with glVertexAttribPointer, I tried VBO with saving tangent as other texture coordinate (as in the demo), I tried DisplayList with glVertexAttrib4f. Result is... **EXACTLY THE SAME.**

Height map is loading correctly, I tried to set it as a diffuse map and it looked OK.
glGetError() gives me No Errors and shader compile logs says so.

It is probably something with camera or init states.

Maybe posting an init code will help.

```
void CDepthBase::OpenGLSet() {

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glClearDepth( 1.0f );
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);



    glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE );
    GLfloat ratio;

    glViewport(0, 0, ResolutionWidth, ResolutionHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, ResolutionWidth / (float)ResolutionHeight, 0.1f, 900.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        MBX("Failed to init GLEW.", "Error");
    }
    if (glewIsSupported("GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object")) {
        VBO_supported = true;


    } else VBO_supported = false;

 glHint( GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE );      
    glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );
 glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glAlphaFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0);
}
```

By the way, I'm using GL Extension Wrangler with extensions.

Shader code & log (this exported file contains code which was directly passed to glShaderSource):

```
Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.


Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Fragment shader(s) linked, vertex shader(s) linked. 


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 varying vec3 lightDir;                                          
 varying vec3 viewDir;
 attribute vec4 tangent;
 void main() 
 { 
 gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
 gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
 vec3 vertexPos = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
 vec3 tn = tangent.xyz;             
 vec3 n = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
 vec3 t = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * tangent.xyz);
 vec3 b = cross(t, n) * -tangent.w;
 mat3 tbnMatrix = mat3(t.x, b.x, n.x,
                       t.y, b.y, n.y,
                       t.z, b.z, n.z);
 lightDir = (gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vertexPos) / 100.0;
 lightDir = tbnMatrix * lightDir;
 viewDir = -vertexPos;
 viewDir = tbnMatrix * viewDir;
 } 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 varying vec3 lightDir;                                          
 varying vec3 viewDir;
 uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;
 uniform sampler2D normalMap;
 uniform sampler2D heightMap;
 uniform float scale;
 uniform float bias;
 void main() 
 { 
 vec3 v = normalize(viewDir);
 vec2 TexCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
{
 float height = texture2D(heightMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st).r;
 height = height * scale + bias;
 TexCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st + (height * v.xy); 
}
 vec3 l = lightDir;
 float atten = max(0.0, 1.0 - dot(l, l));
 l = normalize(l);
 vec3 n = normalize(texture2D(normalMap, TexCoord).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);
 vec3 h = normalize(l + v);
 float nDotL = max(0.0, dot(n, l));
 float nDotH = max(0.0, dot(n, h));
 float power = (nDotL == 0.0) ? 0.0 : pow(nDotH, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
 vec4 ambient = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].ambient * atten;
 vec4 diffuse = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].diffuse * nDotL * atten;
 vec4 specular = gl_FrontLightProduct[0].specular * power * atten;
 vec4 color = gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor + ambient + diffuse + specular;color *= texture2D(diffuseMap,TexCoord);
 gl_FragColor = color ;
 }
```

Uniforms are working correctly because results are the same if I switch them with constant values.
Compiling shader:

```
void __Shader::import(){
    if(imported) __Shader::~__Shader();

        v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); 


        glShaderSource(v, 1, (const GLchar **)&vsrc.cstr,NULL);
        glShaderSource(f, 1, (const GLchar **)&fsrc.cstr,NULL);

        glCompileShader(v);
        glCompileShader(f);

        p = glCreateProgram();

        glAttachShader(p,v);
        glAttachShader(p,f);

        if(_flags & NORMAL_MAPPING) 
            glBindAttribLocation(p, ATTRIB_TANGENT, "tangent");

        glLinkProgram(p);

        if(_flags & DIFFUSE_MAPPING) 
            diffuseUni.loc = glGetUniformLocation(p, "diffuseMap");
        if(_flags & NORMAL_MAPPING) 
            normalUni.loc = glGetUniformLocation(p, "normalMap");
        if(_flags & PARALLAX_MAPPING) 
            heightUni.loc = glGetUniformLocation(p, "heightMap");
        if(_flags & SPECULAR_MAPPING) 
            specularUni.loc = glGetUniformLocation(p, "specularMap");

        imported = true;
}
```

Setting attribute in VBO:

```
    if(tangents.size() > 0){
        buffered |= 3;
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_tangent);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tangent);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tangents.size()*sizeof(tangent), tangents.get_ptr(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

// and in draw:

if(buffered & 3) {

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tangent);    
        glVertexAttribPointer(__Shader::ATTRIB_TANGENT, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);   
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(__Shader::ATTRIB_TANGENT);  
    }
```

and a small note

```
for(int i = 0; i < responders.size(); ++i)
if(strstr(responders[i].idea, "tangent problem"))
responders[i].please_dont_talk();
```

Just tell me your other ideas about what can be the reason of those bad results.

Comment: Please add the information from the later two questions into your first question, then close the later two. One problem only needs one question. If you do that, I'll look at it.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Those are all informations needed.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to vote to close the other two ( [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737914/parallax-mapping-issue-in-glsl-opengl) & [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728555/problem-with-parallax-normal-mapping-in-opengl-glsl) ) as duplicates as this.

Comment: Looks like your shader code is missing from this question, I'll let you edit that in in case anythings changed. Can you also post the code where you set the shader variables?

Comment: I now edited it so there should not be any more code needed.

Comment: @Glorian: if you say that the demo works, try modifying the demo, line by line, into you code. When it stops working look what you've changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wheew... already solved it. The problem was with loading texture files even though I did not see any disorders with diffuse mapping or even with diffuse+normal mapping. I was using IMG_Load from SDL, maybe I used it wrong way but it did not work for me. It was probably normal map messed up.

bad texture import code:

```
if(imported || filenamez.length() < 1) return;
    SDL_Surface* surface = 0;


        surface = IMG_Load(filenamez.c_str());

    if (surface) { 
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    bool endianess = filenamez.substr(filenamez.length()-4) == ".jpg";
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, surface->w, surface->h, 0, 
            (endianess ? GL_RGB : GL_BGR), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

    }
```

BEWARE !

I'm now using HBITMAP-based texture loading taken from dhpoware demo which I was talking about. And it works fine.

**peace.**

After 2-3 days of hard debugging, let me feel a little bit of euphoria.

Oh, I'd forget, the final result:
[image]

Comment: Very nice, looks good. Glad you solved the problem, sorry I didn't explicitly get back to you. Earlier I looked at your stuff, and didn't see anything wrong. I just remembered to come back to take a second look, and you figured out. :)

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem... except I'm using a different language which has it's own image loader. Do you know what the exact difference is in the loaders you used? Are there changes I can make to the shader that compensate for this? I've been experimenting with every variable but they all seem to make things worse when changed...

Comment: Found it! I tried this before, but while there were other problems. When you calculate the normal based on the normal map, negate the y value. Like so:

vec3 n = normalize(texture2D(normalMap, newTexCoord).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0);
n.y = -n.y;

Fixed it right up!